# Finding temperature using an NTC thermistor

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I am given an NTC thermistor with a resistance of 10k ohms at 25 degrees C. For the B model, B=3799K, and when in contact with the object, the thermistor has resistance 5k ohm. I am to find the temperature.

I am unsure how to find the resistance of the thermistor, I am confused with what the resistance of the thermistor is... I had just taken the resistance of the thermistor to be 10k ohms, and ignored the last sentence about how the its resistance changed when it was in contact with the object... I then took the resistance of the object to be 100k ohm, (My lecturer just said that this value relates to temperature, and that at 25 degrees it is 100k ohm.) I also took temperature of the object to be 25 degrees. (I did put all temperatures in kelvin.)

Can someone please help me if I got the values of the variables in the B model equation correct?

Thank you,

Comment: First, find out what a thermistor actually *is* and what it *does.* (there are plenty of books and websites that can teach you that). It seems clear from your post that you don't know those basic facts, so it's not surprising that you can't answer the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of typical applications, a thermistor can be used to measure the temperature of an object.

For that purpose, a thermistor has to have a good thermal contact with an object. If the temperature of the object increases, the temperature of the thermistor will increase as well and its resistance will increase or decrease, depending on its type, PTC or NTC, respectively.

In your example, the resistance of an NTC thermistor ($B=3799K$), in thermal contact with an object, has decreased from the nominal value of $10Kohm$ (at $25C$) to $5Kohm$, which indicates that the temperature of the object is greater than $25C$.

The temperature of the object can be calculated using this formula: $T=\frac {T_0B}{B+T_0\ln \big(\frac R {R_0}\big)}$, which follows from a more familiar thermistor formula: $R=R_0e^{B\big(\frac 1 T - \frac 1 {T_0}\big)}$.

Making all substitutions ($T_0=25C$, $R_0=10Kohm$, $R=5Kohm$ and $B=3977K$), we'll get $T=42C$.

The resistance of the thermistor could be measured using a Wheatstone bridge or a simple resistive divider.

The resistance of the object should not play any role here, since the contact between the thermistor and the object should be thermal - not electrical.